Is it recommended to create custom SearchCriteria?
OOTB does not handle Exposure search for example, say I wanted to create a custom search page, would I be best going down the route of creating a custom ExposureSearchCriteria entity, doing the search-config.xml mapping etc, or simply use the Query API?
Example:
Exposure entity has a foreignkey to a custom Claim_ext.eti (I know, don't ask) with a new varchar column CustomClaimNumber on Claim_ext.eti.
Claim_ext.eti has an array of Exposures on it.
What they want is to have a new search page on from the Search dropdown to be able to search by this CustomClaimNumber, to bring back all exposures that match. Preferably it would be nice to have these exposures searchable by other columns too, they haven't asked for the other columns yet, but I expect them to eventually.

Search is one of the harder aspects to get right. What do you need to search for on the Exposure entity? Please edit your question and add more details, there may be a better way to do this but it would be helpful to know what the business context is. Anonymize if you have to but more context will help people suggest the best modifications to make in ClaimCenter.

Ok, sorry I have to ask just to make sure I have this right. So the current situation is that you have a custom entity called Claim_ext which is not an extension of the OOTB Claim entity, but actually a new entity. Claim_ext has a CustomClaimNumber field that for some reason could not be on the OOTB Claim entity. The business wants to search on this CustomClaimNumber field? All that right? What other information is on the Claim_ext entity? I am asking because I want to know how hard it would be to get rid of it and possibly move those fields to the OOTB Claim entity.

Yes that is correct. It is decade old functionality that we have been landed with.

It is not possible to move the data to the OOTB Claim entity due to the nature of the rest of the data, they technically have claimception, there can be many of these Claim_ext's on a GW claim.etx, it's an odd setup

So the OOTB Claim entity has an array of Claim_ext entities?

Exposure has FK to Claim_ext.eti, Claim_ext.eti then has an array of Exposures

I am just going to summarize your situation as I understand it because this is the understanding I am using to determine what I would do in this situation. If anything in is incorrect let me know and I may change my recommendation.
My Understanding:

You you a custom entity called Claim_etx which has an array of Exposures
The OOTB Exposure entity has a FK to both the OOTB Claim entity and the Claim_etx entity
The Claim_etx entity has a CustomClaimNumber field that you want to search on. Because of this data model design each Claim.ClaimNumber can (and is intended to) map to more than 1 Claim_etx.CustomClaimNumber. However the reverse relationship is that each Claim_etx.CustomClaimNumber maps to one (and only one) Claim.ClaimNumber? Please confirm if the last sentence is true.
The business would like to be able search on this CustomClaimNumber field on Claim_etx. There is no other fields on Claim_etx the business wants to search on.

If all this is correct then I would probably not bother with creating all the virtual entities, search widgets, and modifications to the search-config.xml that you would need to make in order to have this work within the search framework. I would create a quick and simple search PCF that uses a query builder to bring back AtMostOneRow from this Claim_etx entity and has a push link to the Claim if the search returns a result.
The reason I recommend this is I think this data model modification is not ideal and Guidewire will at some point (especially if you are on-premise now and decide to move to the cloud) in the future ask that it be refactored into something else. Is this ClaimCenter implementation in the cloud now? I think whatever search functionality you create should be quick and simple because you should assume it will be removed at some point later when Guidewire asks you to clean up the data model. This is just my opinion but I hope this helps.

Any of the SearchCriteria classes are basically just giant wrappers for the Query API. The idea behind the criteria class is to allow the information to be stored within the class that you select on the UI. So if you have a Jurisdiction drop down you would store that in a variable within the class so when you performSearch() that information is readily available for your query.
